# Concatenate DASH audio and video to single file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

First of all, I have a folder with about 200 video and audio segments (m4v and m4a) of a video that was live streamed as DASH video. Now - without having the original file - I want to concatenate those parts to a single, playable video file.

To mention what I already tested:

- concatenate via the Unix terminal command cat; unfortunately this won't help to make the video playable in any media player again
- using ffmpeg's merge abilities via files.txt; with the same unsuccessful result

I'm definitely not an expert (otherwise I probably wouldn't ask) but the problem may be also the missing mpd and/or init file (as far as I could skim in the standard).

Don't get me wrong: I **don't** want to get a bit to bit identical result of the original file. All I want to achieve is a single playable mp4 file of aforesaid video.

I also tried to make a own mpd file, but the "stream" won't play. FYI, I tried playing it in the current VLC 3.0.0 git, since the current stable versions seems not to support DASH.
If it helps, here the video codec:

```
id="live-hd_H264"
mimeType="video/mp4"
codecs="avc1.4d401f"
width="396"
height="704"
```

So, can anybody help me?

Kind regards!

Comment: What did you try with ffmpeg?

Comment: I made a files.txt with a list of all chunks and hoped ffmpeg will find the video stream but it failed with:

could not find corresponding track id 1
could not find corresponding trex
error reading header
video.m4v: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: If you share a couple of the m4v and m4a files, we can check.

Comment: I know the codec and bitrate and tried to make such a mpd file but with no luck.

Comment: Only want the segments, not the manifest.

Comment: Here's a video segment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxfI8i8WYBsQLUR0a0ZyS1BLaWM

Comment: I don't want **a** video segment, a couple of video and audio segments, please.

Comment: Okay, sorry! https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxfI8i8WYBsQUld3bHpNRGh2Slk

Comment: I get this error with mp4box: '[iso file] Movie fragment but no moov (yet) - possibly broken parsing!'  How were these files generated? If you haven't, can you upload the very first segment to that Drive folder.

Comment: The problem is, I don't have that very first segment (called init). Those segments were "captured" via curl from an Instagram live stream (don't ask why so complicated)

Comment: Knowing that to moov atom is missing is there a way to write it? Maybe with untrunc? 
Other question: Is it possible to binary concatenate m4v/m4a like the HLS segments?

Comment: Quick update: The website [link[(http://mp4repair.org/pwt6/preview.html) would be able to recover the file. This means the file is definitely restorable. But I'm not willing to pay 50 USD. Do you know a way to do the method of the website for free?

Comment: [Yes](https://superuser.com/a/1033364/114058) but a good reference is required.

Comment: That's a problem, since I don't have any similar video. And I think just converting any arbitrary video to m4v will not not be good enough. Is there at least a fix for the audio?

Comment: Can you tap into another Instagram stream and capture its init file? I'm fairly sure Instagram has a standardized format.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks! I'll look into that.

Comment: Okay, thanks again for the clue. I was now able to recover the single files with a tool called movdump. The only remaining problem: I need to re-encode the chunks, but ffmpeg fails with 'co located POCs unavailable'.

Comment: Sounds like a segment refers to frames in other segments for decoding. Try catting and then movdump, or the other way around, before feeding it to ffmpeg.